# running installed web application

Tags: asp.net

I created a set up project and installed a web application on my local machine. The set up was completed successfuly. How to check if the application has got installed properly.

Comment: You should see it on IIS, check there the bindings (on which address can be accessed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to the URL.  if the application is named "MyWebApp" navigate to http://localhost/mywebapp/

Answer (score 0):

You can run the application through visual studio or navigate to it through your web browser.
F5 (or debug run)